# Formatting text output in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, formatting

I have some output from a pdsh I want to format it to load into a DB. I need it in 3 columns and essentially want the Module ID and the message on one line. Bellow is the output i have:

```
10.125.45.58,scope, Module ID     = server-1
10.125.45.58,scope, Message       = Correctable memory error
10.125.45.58,scope, Module ID     = server-2
10.125.45.58,scope, Message       = Correctable memory error
```

This is the output i need:

```
10.125.45.58,scope,server-1 Correctable memory error
10.125.45.58,scope,server-2 Correctable memory error
```

I have been awking and seding...i cant work it out any ideas?

Here is what I've done so far

```
cat myfile.txt | sed -e "s/:/\,scope\,/g" | grep -E '(Module ID|Message)'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the `awk` and `sed` you've done so far?

Comment: Hey, thanks...i dont have any that work or even close, i have already formated the origanl output from the pdsh... # cat myfile.txt | sed -e  "s/:/\,scope\,/g" | grep -E '(Module ID|Message)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
10.125.45.58,scope, Module ID     = server-1
10.125.45.58,scope, Message       = Correctable memory error
10.125.45.58,scope, Module ID     = server-2
10.125.45.58,scope, Message       = Correctable memory error 

$ sed 'N; s/\n.*=//; s/ *Module ID.*= *//' ip.txt 
10.125.45.58,scope,server-1 Correctable memory error
10.125.45.58,scope,server-2 Correctable memory error
```

- `N` get next line, so the substitution works for every two lines considered together
- `s/\n.*=//;` delete from newline character to last `=`
- `s/ *Module ID.*= *//` then delete everything from `Module ID` upto `=` with optional spaces around

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on single lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for portability, efficiency, simplicity, clarity, maintainability, and most other desirable attributes of software:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{srvr=$NF;next} {ip=$1; sub(/.*=/,""); print ip srvr $0}' file
10.125.45.58,scope,server-1 Correctable memory error
10.125.45.58,scope,server-2 Correctable memory error
```